# rails print array in select_tag printing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following code:

```
<%= f.select_tag :language, Settings.supported_languages.collect {|p| [ p.value, p.key ] }%>
```

that should print a array in the select_tag from rails ...

But I got this error:

```
undefined method `value' for ["Deutsch", :de]:Array
```

how should it look corretly?

Comment: what does `Settings.supported_languages` return?

Comment: What does `Settings.supported_languages` contain?

Comment: It's shown above. An Array Like its mentiond above: {"Deutsch"=>:de, "English"=>:en}

Comment: if I do this: Settings.supported_languages its the array and if I do this Settings.supported_languages.all its the hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this code use

`<%= f.select_tag :language, Settings.supported_languages.collect {|p| [ p[0], p[1] ] }%>`

Comment: undefined method `select_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x0000000952aae0>

Comment: I do not know the context, but usually you use `f.select` or `select_tag`. Try to change it.